Points in the locale associated with the coframe of sublocales
Given a locale $L$, the sublocales of $L$ form a coframe. We can reverse the containment relation to get a frame, which gives us another locale $\mathfrak{C}(L)$. It has a canonical map $\mathfrak{C}(L) \to L$, setting the inverse image of the open $U \subseteq L$ to be the open sublocale $U$. This map is both mono and epi, so the points of $\mathfrak{C}(L)$ is a subset of the points of $L$, but epimorphism doesn't necessarily induce a surjection of points.
Can we characterize the points of this locale? What do they correspond to? As a related question, what is the geometric intuition for $\mathfrak{C}(L)$? This setup looks like we have the counit of an adjunction, is this true?

The dissolution locale can be considered a replacement for the set of points of a topological space. Vermeulen's proof that a locale with closed product projections is compact is basically the same as Bourbaki's proof for topological spaces, except for replacing the discrete space of points with the dissolution locale.

Yes, the dissolution locale of $L$ has the same points of $L$.
See page 96 in Johnstone's The Art of Pointless Thinking: A Student's Guide to The Category of Locales.  He also points out that the operation of passing to the dissolution locale is not idempotent, so cannot be a counit of a coreflective subcategory.
In the same paragraph, Johnstone provides some intuition for the dissolution locale:

… we may think of it as something like the discrete modification of a space … the result of declaring all sublocales of $L$ to be closed …

In particular, discontinuous functions on $L$ could be defined as morphisms out of the dissolution locale of $L$.
Additional references include Frames and Locales by Picado and Pultr, who devote several sections to dissolution locales.  There is also a recent paper by Picado–Pultr on dissolution locales.
